# How to add scrollbar in gwt in flowpanel?

Tags: gwt

i am developing an mobile application and i have a problem that i can not add scrollbar in it. 
i want to add scroll bar in my flow panel and i also want to fix my flowpanel's size fit to screen size. 
if anyone knows the solution pls tell me
thanks in adv....

Answer (score 0):

Window.getClientWidth() and Window.getClientHeight() will give you the client area
To add scrolling, just use ScrollPanel

Answer (score 0):

ScrollPanel comes from the Base class SimplePanel and can only have one child.

To add scrollbar, use the below css class:

```
.add-scrollbar {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

GWT Code:

```
FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();
panel.setStyleName("add-scrollbar");
```

Comment: How is this as answer top the question ?

Comment: @Rohit: I added the disadvantage of ScrollPanel